# How to automatically sort Quickfix entries by line text in Vim?

Tags: list, sorting, vim, dictionary

I’m trying to automatically sort the lines in the Quickfix list alphabetically by the contents of the lines themselves (by default, it sorts by the order they appear in the file). I’ve put the below in my `.vimrc`, but for some reason it sorts according to the line numbers. As far as I can tell, the Quickfix list is a list of dictionaries, so the `Sortqfbytext` function below should only be sorting by the `text` content of each list item and ignoring the rest (including the line numbers).

```
function! s:Sortqfbytext(i1, i2)
  let textlist = []
  let textlist = [a:i1.text,a:i2.text]
  call sort(textlist)
  if textlist[0] == textlist[1]
    return 0
  elseif textlist[0] == a:i1.text
    return 1
  elseif textlist[0] == a:i2.text
    return -1
  endif
endfunction

function! s:Makesortedqflist()
  let xlist = sort(getqflist(), 's:Sortqfbytext')
  call setqflist(xlist)
endfunction

autocmd! QuickfixCmdPost * call s:Makesortedqflist()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the Quickfix list"?  I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The quickfix list is a list of errors with links to where they are. For example, if you type
    :vimgrep /readme/ &
    :copen
It will open the quickfix windows with links to all of the instances of "readme" in the current file. However, the quickfix window can't itself be edited because it messes up the links. So, to sort it, you have to make a new list, edit the list, and then set the new quickfix list by calling setqflist(newlisthere).

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to sort a list of dictionaries alphabetically by only one item in the dictionary (in this case, the 'text' item).

Comment: Ah, this has nothing to do with the QuickFIX engine for FIX protocol, does it?  Please be more careful with your tags in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this idea as follows.

```
autocmd! QuickfixCmdPost * call SortQuickfix('QfStrCmp')

function! SortQuickfix(fn)
    call setqflist(sort(getqflist(), a:fn))
endfunction

function! QfStrCmp(e1, e2)
    let [t1, t2] = [a:e1.text, a:e2.text]
    return t1 <# t2 ? -1 : t1 ==# t2 ? 0 : 1
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

QuickFix list update setqflist() needs the `'r'` flag.

Just change `call setqflist(xlist)` to `call setqflist(xlist, 'r')`